# Does this code need optimization?I wrote this code without any reference and only with knowledge of datastructure

Tags: c, string

i wrote this code without looking on the net and having a look in the builtin.

how can remove that temp variable and write directly in one of the variable passed in strcat12()?

```
#include <stdio.h>

char temp[]="";

int strlen12(char *str) {
int count = 0;
while(*str) {
    count++;
    str++;
  }

 return count;
}

char strcat12(char *str, char *str2) {
int i = 0;
int l = strlen12(str);
    while(*str) {
        temp[i++] = *str;
        str++;
}

while(*str2) {
    temp[l++] = *str2;
    str2++;
}   
}
```

Comment: Did you compile?

Comment: This is undefined behavior, anyway. `temp` is of size 1.

Comment: You gotta malloc temp, that doesn't look good

Comment: the posted code does not compile!  especially the function: `strcat12()` is declared to return a `char`, but the body of the function does not return anything

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) via a single blank line 2) separate functions by 2 or 3 blank lines (be consistent)  3) consistently indent the code.  indent after every opening brace '{'.  unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces.

Comment: the variable `temp` is only a single byte in size.  So statements like: `temp[i++] = *str;` and `temp[l++] = *str2;` are accessing beyond the end of the array,  This is undefined behavior and can lead to a seg fault event.

Comment: it did with gcc and i made all the change listed below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code has some errors and some place on which it can comply with standard.

`strlen` function returns the length of the string. Better would be if you return `size_t` and parameter is of type `const char*`.

Now `strcat` doesn't behave the way you implemented it. What happens then? Standard says

```
 char *strcat(char * restrict s1, const char * restrict s2);
```

The `strcat` function appends a copy of the string pointed to by `s2` (including the terminating null character) to the end of the string pointed to by `s1`. The initial character of `s2` overwrites the null character at the end of `s1`. If copying takes place between objects that overlap, the behavior is undefined.

Returns

The `strcat` function returns the value of `s1`.

```
char * mystrcat(char *dest, const char *src)
{
    size_t i=0,j=0;
    while( dest[i] ) i++ ;
    while( src[j]  ) { dest[i+j] = src[j]; j++; }
    dest[i+j] = '\0';
    return dest;
}
```

The same way `strlen()` returns `size_t`.

```
size_t strlen(const char *s){
    size_t len = 0;
    for( ; s[len] ; len++ )
         ;
     return len;
}
```

Now the problems in your code

- `char temp[]=""` this is an one length string containing only the single character `\0`.
- This is not a good idea to have a function that will fill one of the `char` array when called with 2 strings. This side effect is not desirable and it is not reusable.
- `char strcat12(char *str, char *str2)` You are supposed to return a `char` but you returned nothing.
- `char strcat12(char *str, char *str2)` Again why do you want to return a `char`?
- Now if you are using a global variable why do you even need to return anything as far as the code is given. `void strcat12(char *str, char *str2)` will be ok.

A slightly better idea can be that you will return a `char*` which will contain the concatenated string. What I mean by this is you will allocate memory and return pointer to that memory and the memory holds concatenated string.

Comment: thanks some of people don't understand problem we face as student oi this new system. Thanks a lot i aforementioned i did have a look at the builtin i just used strlen in some code and then i had an idea to rewrite.

Answer (score 0):

regarding your question: *how can remove that temp variable and write directly in one of the variable passed in strcat12()?*

to write directly into the parameter 'str', the array pointed to by 'str' must be long enough to hold the contents of both parameters + the terminating NUL byte.

Then the variable `temp[]` does not need to be referenced.

here is one way to implement the `strcat12()` function:

```
char * strcat12(char *dest, const char *src)
{
    size_t i;
    for (i = 0; dest[i]; i++);

    for (size_t j = 0; src[j]; j++)
        dest[i+j] = src[j];

    dest[i+j] = '\0';
    return dest;
}
```